# How to prevent rendering when a recoil value updates

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I have a component having the recoil-property "left". It's a simple atom containing a string | number | null | undefined.

Now, I do have second component. It has a chart which get an options object containing a click listener. When clicking, the value "left" is read and depending on the state, magic happens.

The problem I have is that the component containing the chart triggers a render everytime "left"-value updates, because the click listener is defined in that component. Normally, this wouldn't be a problem, however, the chart rendering takes about a second making it an issue. What is the recommended approach to overcome this problem?

As far as I know, recoil hooks can't be used outside of components which leads to this problem in the first place.
a) Am I supposed to save the value "left" to the window object every time it updates?
b) Am I supposed to throw an event and catch that event on another component which does not take that much computing time for rendering?

What is the recoil-way? There has to be a way of telling recoil to only fetch the value when needed and not while compiling a click listener.